# How to add a Parse objectId back into my database in php?

Tags: php, parse-platform

I just used a POST curl statement in PHP to add an object from my database (on my server) to my Parse.com database. How do I then get the `objectId` of the item I just created, so that I can add it back onto my server's database?

This is my first guess on how to get the `objectId` from Parse and put it in my database:

```
$headers = array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",  
   "X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,
   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey
);          


$url = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/myClassName?";
$query = urlencode('where={\"siteID\":\"theSiteIdUsedToCreateThePOST\"}');
$rest = curl_init($url .$query);   
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1);
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,"GET");  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);   
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($rest);  
echo $response;   
//Will this return the objectId of the specific site


//Now connecting to database

$linkDB = dbGNSC_connect() or exit();
$queryFromDB  = "SELECT * FROM tblFromDB";
$result = mysql_query($queryFromDB, $linkDB);

$queryInfoFromParseToDatabase = 
    "UPDATE tblFromDB SET ObjectID = **HELPMEOUT** 
     WHERE SiteID = 'theSiteIdUsedToCreateThePOST'";
mysql_query($result, queryInfoFromParseToDatabase );
```

How can I get the `objectID` to put into the query for my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option, [the Parse API should return JSON.](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#objects-creating-objects) To get the object ID from the result, I think you should be able to just do this:

```
$objectID = json_decode($result)->objectId;
```

Comment: Should I put this under my line of echo $response?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion of using mysqli, I will try it out and see how it goes. Thank you for all your help!